# Open/rescue large vmdk files with little ram and HDD memory

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmdk

I have a vmdk file (approx. 800 GB), it contains many large media files. Unfortunately, the ESXI VM is filled to the last bit. The attempt of a subsequent enlargement was already some years ago, so that only this vmdk file is still contained.

Is there any way to recover this data? Especially since the file could be corrupt.

**Information:**

Host: 2 TB SSD - Only 500 GB Free (System and vmdk)

VMDK File: 800 GB

**Try 7-Zip:**

7-Tip loads the vmdk and shows me the two partitions 0.img and 1.img it contains. (Probably boot and file partition).
However, as soon as I want to open one of the files, 7-zip wants to load everything temporarily. So unpack 800 GB (host has only 1 TB).

On direct unzip to another drive:

> Unexpected end of file
> Unexpected end of file
>
> Warning
>
> The file cannot be opened as a [VMDK] archive.
>
> The file was opened as a [GPT] archive.

**Try ESXi/Workstation:**

Here the systems report with different errors. I will add this later.

Did have anyone ideas on how to rescue the data?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the results of the attempts to open it with VMWare, in particular those errors you implied. Showing your work makes for a better question, more likely you get you responses.